# Why couldn't I deal with argument in java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm java virgin. I've made really simple code like below.

```
class TreeData implements Comparable<TreeData> {
    private String sixString;
    private ArrayList<Integer> stringNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> charNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public TreeData(String sixString, int stringNum, int charNum){
        this.sixString = sixString;
        (this.stringNum).add(stringNum);
        (this.charNum).add(charNum);
    }

    public int compareTo(TreeData other) {
        return sixString.compareTo(other.getSixString());
    }

    public String getSixString(){
        return sixString;
    }
}



class Child<T extends Comparable<T>>{
    public void print(T data){
        //error : String a = data.getSixString();
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child<TreeData> child = new Child<TreeData>();
        TreeData td = new TreeData("sixString", 8, 2);
        child.print(td);
    }
}
```

I had a problem in 'print' method in the Child class. When I tried calling the getSixString() method of data(passed as argument), it occurs error. I don't know why I can't using public method in the argument 'data'. Is it related with Generic? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What is the error your get?

Comment: The method getSixString() is undefined for the type T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Child class, you only define T to be extending Comparable. Yet you expect it to have the method getSixString which Comparable doesn't have. What you probably want it for it to be extending TreeData:

```
class Child<T extends TreeData>{
    public void print(T data){
        String a = data.getSixString();
        //should work now since T defines getSixString()
    }
}
```

Or better yet if all you want is for T to be TreeData, you don't need any generic class. I'm assuming your real intention was:

```
class Child extends TreeData {
    public void print(){
        String a = getSixString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first code is what I intended. But why it doesn't work if I change like this : class Child<T>{ ....} instead of class Child<T extends TreeData> ??

Comment: And in my original code,  I thinks "class Child<T extends Comparable<T>>" is right because TreeData extends Comparable<TreeData>?

Comment: Because as I've explained in my answer, a generic type can be anything, unless you constraint it. A simple `T` can be anything including but not limited to `TreeData`, and not all data types / classes have the `getSixString` public method. You have to constraint your `T` if you want to include specific methods that not all objects have. Again if you only do `Child<T extends Comparable<T>>` you're not enforcing that `T` will be `TreeData` and will have `getSixString` - it can be any type that extends Comparable, even `Integer`, for example, which doesn't have `getSixString()`

Comment: OMG, now i understand... Then, there is no way to constrain "T" to "TreeData extending Comparable<Treedata>" ???

Comment: `TreeData` already has that constraint so as long as you constraint `T` to be TreeData or a subclass of it (Child<T extends TreeData>), your constraint will hold.